# Fatal error when trying to login to phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 and 5.1.3 (PHP 8.1.3/MariaDB 10.5.15)

Tags: phpmyadmin, fatal-error

When I try to login to phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 and 5.1.3 (PHP 8.1/MariaDB 10.5.15), after entering a username and password, and clicking the "Go" button, I get this error:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php:125 Stack
> trace: #0
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php(125):
> mysqli->real_connect() #1
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php(2631):
> PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli->connect() #2
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(380):
> PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->connect() #3
> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(23): require_once('...') #4 {main}
> thrown in
> **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Dbi/DbiMysqli.php** on line **125**

Here is line 125 of DbiMysqli.php:

```
        $return_value = $mysqli->real_connect(
            $host, // <---- This is line 125
            $user,
            $password,
            '',
            $server['port'],
            (string) $server['socket'],
            $client_flags
        );
```

Here is line 2361 of DatabaseInterface.php:

```
        if (! $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['DisableIS'] || $type === 'super') { // <--line 2361
            // Prepare query for each user type check
```

Here is line 380 of common.inc.php:

```
        // Connects to the server (validates user's login)
        /** @var DatabaseInterface $userlink */
        $userlink = $GLOBALS['dbi']->connect(DatabaseInterface::CONNECT_USER); // <--line 380
```

Here is line 23 of index.php:

```
require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/common.inc.php';
```

I am not sure I am entering the correct username/password at the phpMyAdmin login screen, but I don't think this should matter: I shouldn't get a Fatal error in either case.

A note about my version of phpMyAdmin.  I got this error on a fresh install of phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 on a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10 with fresh installs of PHP 8.1.3 and MariaDB 10.5.15.  When I saw that 5.0.4 is slightly old, I tried to upgrade it, but 5.0.4 was the latest package for my version of Ubuntu.  So then I tried to upgrade using `composer create-project phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`, and the composer install of phpMyAdmin 5.1.3 appeared to be successful, but the version number shown at the top-left of the documentation (when clicking the question mark next to "Log in" on index.php) remained 5.0.4.  I also tried [downloading](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) the zip file of 5.1.3, extracting it, and copying the files over into the phpmyadmin directory, but, still, the documentation says "5.0.4".  I presume I am running 5.1.3 at this point, as that's the version number shown at the top of package.json, but I have no way of telling for sure.  It hasn't cleared up the error or the line numbers.

Comment: If you think there's a bug in phpMyAdmin then please open a bug report on their GitHub page. This isn't really a topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If phpMyAdmnin is telling you that you are running phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 then that is the version that you are running. It is not compatible with PHP 8.1.

Either upgrade your phpMyAdmin version or downgrade PHP to PHP 8.0.

Comment: I couldn't find anything online saying that phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 is not compatible with PHP 8.1, so thanks. Do you know how to upgrade phpMyAdmin to the version 5.1.3 (or install from fresh) on Ubuntu? Latest package is 5.0.4. I tried to install 5.1.3 using Composer, but I wasn't sure that that worked, either, and then I tried copying files over, but that didn't work, either. Then I tried uninstalling the package and re-installing via Composer.  Now when I go to https://example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php I just get a 404 Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: @RobertKS It sounds like you copied the files into the wrong folder.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Composer does not install in /usr/share/ like the Ubuntu package does.  So when you use the package to install phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 but then use Composer to install phpMyAdmin 5.1.3, the alias directive `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf (which is residual from the package installation) will misdirect browser request to the wrong server folder.  Comment out that Alias line in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf and the login page will show up again. In any case, as Dharman said, phpMyAdmin 5.0.4 is not compatible with PHP 8.1.  SOLVED.